# How to cover beforeDestroy hook in jest code coverage

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I have following beforeDestroy hook in Employee.vue file

```
beforeDestroy() {
    this.checkIncompleteValues()
}
```

and in test file unit test written as

```
test('beforeDestroy method', () => {
    const beforeDestroySpy = jest.spyOn(Employee, 'beforeDestroy')
    wrapper.vm.callOtherMethod = jest.fn()
    expect(beforeDestroySpy).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(mockedMethod).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

The above test has been passed but in code coverage report beforeDestroy lines not covered as u can see in the image
[coverage report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSffE.png)

Is there any way to cover the lines which are present in beforeDestroy hook

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

destroy the instance of the component e.g `wrapper.destroy()`.

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import sinon from 'sinon'

const spy = sinon.stub()
mount({
  render: null,
  destroyed() {
    spy()
  }
}).destroy()
expect(spy.calledOnce).toBe(true)
```

Note: For functional components, `destroy` only removes the rendered DOM elements from the document.

Docs: https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#destroy

Comment: hi @doesnotmatter, thanks for ur solution, it worked